# Possible to enumerate a collection to an array in just one line?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, can this be reduced to just one line?

```
results = []
Object.all.each { |o| results <<  o if o == 1 }
results
```

I am thinking it is with enum_for, but can't figure it out.

Comment: check http://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the wealth of methods in [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html):

```
Object.all.select { |o| o == 1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this?

```
Object.all.select{|o| o == 1}
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't mean to confuse with "Object"--that was meant to be anything.